# changing button text inside gridview using vb.net

Tags: button, gridview

I'm new in vb.net. I have some questions how to implement this..I have gridview and the button will change depending on the column status..if it's status is "Blocked" the button will be "Unblock" and if the status is blank the button will be "Block". **My other problem is after clicking the button the selected row button will update in the database and change the status to blocked if user clicked the "Block" then again the button will change again to "Unblock" button and vice versa.** Your help is much appreciated..

Status | Unblock/Block

(blank)|    Block(button)

Blocked|    Block(it should be Unblock button)

What's wrong with this code..why is it not working?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AllowStatus" 
        HeaderText="" ReadOnly="True" 
        SortExpression="AllowStatus"> 
        <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Block/Unblock">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BlockButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="" Text="Block" />
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>




Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) ' Handles GridView1.RowDataBound **<<ooops my mistake I comment out this >.< ..that's why it's not working**
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim allowstatus As String = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AllowStatus")).ToString
            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("BlockButton"), Button)
            If allowstatus = "Blocked" Then
                btn.Text = "Unblocked"
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handle GridView1_RowDataBound event. Based on value of column (blocked/EmptyString), use FindControl to locate button and change its text to block/unblock

Comment: but how can I iterate the thousand of data to change the text button on loading the page?

Comment: when you bind data to grid, RowDataBound event is raised for each row after data is bound to UI control. At this point of time, you know column status (blocked/EmptyString). You can decide the Label of button based on that

Comment: Ah I see..that's the function of RowDataBound..Thanks for that..Sorry but how will I know if the status (blocked/EmptyString)?..What will be the exact syntax for vb.net?..Thanks